# Why does it work when I append a new element to a TUPLE?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, mutable

Since Tuples are non-mutable data types in Python and Tuple comprehensions aren't a thing then why do List comprehensions with circle brackets instead of square brackets work fine and produce regular Tuples?

I thought circular brackets were used to define Tuples not Lists (I know I'm not wrong there).

From my understanding I'm appending values to a Tuple that has already been defined and I'm able to update a Tuple and that's not supposed to happen (in Python) as Tuples are non-mutable.

I'm not getting any errors, someone please tell me there is a rational explanation to this.

This is my code:

```
ignore = (r"^\@define\s")
x = tuple()
(x.append(True if re.search(regex, line) else False) for regex in ignore)
if True in x:
  print("How is this possible?")
```

Comment: Its a generator comprehension, not a tuple comprehension. It produces a lazy sequence, rather than an eager sequence produced by a list comprehension.

Comment: @PaulRooney I'm running `x.append()` and `x` is defined is defined as `tuple()`, surely you shouldn't be able to run `append()` on a `tuple()`.

Comment: Right, a generator *expression* that never gets evaluated, so it doesn't throw any errors. As an aside, you should *never* use a mutator method in a comprehension construct. That's mixing a functional construct with state change - it's just bad form.

Comment: I don't get anything from this. x is still an empty tuple.

Comment: @JoshEnglish Yup, as it should be.

Comment: Does your code actually print "WTF?!" ?

Comment: "Basically I'm appending values to a Tuple" no, you are not.

Comment: "I thought circular brackets were used to define Tuples not Lists (I know I'm not wrong there)." You thought wrong there. A tuple is produced by commas, eg `1,2,3`, you only need to enclose it in parentheses if it would be ambiguous without  them.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, yes it does 

Comment: Thank you all for your time and patience, I really appreciate that you've all helped me out.

Comment: It does not print anything when I run it with Python 2.7.9: neither "WTF?!" nor "How is this possible?" prints.  If your confusion is based upon your code printing something because `if True in x` is is true, then something is wrong in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An error isn't being thrown because you are using a *generator expression*.

```
>>> x = tuple()
>>> x
()
>>> (x.append(i) for i in range(10))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x110bede60>
```

Generators are evaluated lazily, and since you haven't even captured the generator in a variable, it just gets garbage collected. However, look what happens when I *do* use the generator:

```
>>> g = (x.append(i) for i in range(10))
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

A *generator* is a quick, cool way to write iterators. A *generator* expression is essentially a "list comprehension for generators", but you can write a generator by using `yield`:

```
>>> def my_generator():
...   yield 1
...   yield 3
...
>>> g = my_generator()
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
3
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> list(my_generator())
[1, 3]
>>>
```

Now, the cool thing about generator expressions is you can combine them with the `tuple` constructor, which takes any iterable, and you sort of have a poor-man's tuple comprehension! *Note, you can drop the parentheses in a function argument if there is only one parameter :

```
>>> tuple(x for x in range(20))
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
>>>
```

As an aside, you should *never* run code like this:

```
>>> x = []
>>> [x.append(i) for i in range(10)]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Firstly, it's wasteful because it creates a list of `None` that is totally useless. Second, it is mixing a functional construct, a list comprehension, with state change (`.append`), which is bad form. Python programmers expect list comprehensions not to do that. *Just use a for-loop for imperative code*.

Comment: Not a real addition, but for clarity you should add "how to create inline a tuple from a generator expression" (`tuple(gen)`) - so that the ones who suffer from this (I know I did in the past) directly can compare the different syntax between a generator expression and creating a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me and for the in-depth answer.

Answer (score 4):

Let's showcase a simpler example, in such a form as to let you follow along at home in your REPL:

```
>>> def error(): raise Exception
...
>>> (error() for x in range(5))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fb1a371f2d0>
```

`(error() for x in range(5)` is a genexp -- a generator expression. When it's evaluated, it produces a generator object which can lazily generates items on demand -- but right now, we haven't asked it to generate anything! Consequently, none of the code contained therein has run.

By contrast, let's see what happens when we try to expand our generator's output into a tuple:

```
>>> tuple(_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in error
Exception
```

Boom!

Comment: Not a real addition, but for clarity you should add "how to create inline a tuple from a generator expression" (`tuple(gen)`)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me, appreciate it.